# Wildcard (alternative) in .clang_complete

Tags: c++, emacs, clang, spacemacs

I am using spacemacs to work on a rather large project written in C++ and built using cmake. I would like to use clang for tab completion. In order to do this I have to make all headers known to clang. There I run into a problem.

I would like to use a project level .clang_complete file. Most of the headers lie in the following directory structure:

```
src/Modules/<module_name>/include
```

Since the number of Modules can vary (and there are quite a few of them) I wanted to add a line like this into the .clang_complete:

```
-I ~/Modules/*/include
```

However, it seems to me that clang does not expand this wildcard (fatal error file not found). If instead I enter all the module names by hand everything works out perfectly.

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS with clang-3.8.

So my question is: *What is the 'clang-idiomatic' way to go about this issue?*